# Authenticate user using Go and Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: flutter, go, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Is there a way to authenticate the user using its email address and password?
In the Firebase Admin SDK package, Go language, I found no "Sign in" function. To create a `CustomToken` you don't need the user's password. I could create a Sign up/Register function using the `CreateUser` function.

The frontend is written in Flutter and yes, I know, it would be possible to implement the authentication directly in the frontend, but I would like to avoid it.

```
func (svc *AuthenticationService) Login(ctx context.Context, req *LoginRequest) (*AuthResponse, error) {
    initFirebase()

    authToken, err := authClient.CustomToken(context.Background(), req.EmailAddress)
    if err != nil {
        return &AuthResponse{
            Result: Result_LOGIN_FAILED,
            Token:  "",
        }, errors.New("login failed: " + err.Error())
    }

    return &AuthResponse{
        Result: Result_LOGIN_SUCCEDED,
        Token:  authToken,
    }, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Admin SDKs, including the one for Go, provide full administrative access to Firebase, and don't have the concept of a currently signed in user. If you want to mint a token for a known user, similar to what the client-side SDKs do, you'd typically [call the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password).

If you want to execute some logic in your Go backend that requires you to know the current user, you'd typically [get the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) on the client, pass that to the server over some secure mechanism, [verify the token there](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk), and then check (for example) of the user is authorized for the operation they're trying to perform.